# Can Windows (WER) generate minidumps and full dumps at the same time of a crashing process?

Tags: debugging, crash, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

We have an application deployed on lots of clients and we want to configure Windows so it gathers dumps of the application if it crashes. As crashes are not frequent we want to be sure to have enough information on the dump to find the source of the issue so we configured Windows to generate full dumps.

Given that the clients have slow upload speeds and the dump is about 800 MB, we were thinking on generating a minidump and a full dump at the same time to gather the full only if the minidump does not contain enough information to debug.

Is this possible? In case that it is not possible can we extract a minidump from a dump with a commandline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO it is not possible to have both types created by WER.

A dump can be converted with WinDbg:

1. Open the full dump
2. `.dump /mFhutip c:\small.dmp` Check which options you want. Note: for a full .NET analysis, you typically need full memory.

You can automate this task by using `cdb` instead of `windbg` and pass commands via the `-c "<command>"` command line switch, e.g.:

```
cdb -c ".dump /mFhutip c:\debug\dumps\small.dmp ; q" -z c:\debug\dumps\big.dmp
```

Comment: ` -c ".dump /mFhutip /c \"Converted from a large WER dump\" c:\....dmp ; q" ` might be nice so someone knows more information is potentially available.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for.